# How to check core data stored particular attribute values null or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to write some condition for core data particular attribute stored values available or not by using If. Please help me, below I have posted my code.

```
// Reading Data from Core DB - STEP #1
        if ([NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name.length > 0"]) {
            // All objects are [NSNull null]
            NSLog(@"YES DATA AVAILABLE IN CORE DB");

        } else {
            // Some objects are of different types(may be NSString)
            NSLog(@"NO DATA AVAILABLE IN CORE DB");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can only apply a `NSPredicate` on a set of data, or a fetch request.
Second, I think you got your comment in the first if clause the other way round.
Third, checking the length of a string and for `null` are two different things.

Not sure what you need help with - this is pretty basic stuff. I recommend you first look at some tutorials and then come back to this problem.